# Anomaly/outlier detection using fuzzy clustering

Tags: clustering, unsupervised-learning, fuzzy

I understand that fuzzy clustering using FCM produces a membership matrix for the set of data points we feed to it. What characteristics will an anomalous cluster produced during this method have? (Considering I only have unlabelled data)

Comment: What is "anomalous" to you? This is very domain specific.